# Merging lists from different urls in Python

Tags: python, list, urllib

I want to get a list of events as values on my y axis, but there is something I can't figure out. This is the code I have so far.

```
eventurl = "http://data.hisparc.nl/show/source/eventtime/501/2017/1/"
for dag in range(1, 32):
    print(eventurl + str(dag))

    data = urllib.request.urlopen(eventurl + str(dag))
    data = data.read().decode()

    events = data.split("# bin\tvalue")
    nevents = [d.split("\t")[1] for d in events[1].strip().split("\n")]
    events_per_hour = list(map(int, nevents))
    print(events_per_hour)
```

When I run this code, this is the (part of the) outcome:

```
http://data.hisparc.nl/show/source/eventtime/501/2017/1/3
[2262, 2299, 2227, 2310, 2240, 2295, 2271, 2316, 2235, 2260, 2269, 2272, 2263, 2302, 2270, 2296, 2353, 2353, 2357, 2298, 2193, 2297, 2393, 2354] 
http://data.hisparc.nl/show/source/eventtime/501/2017/1/4
[2377, 2336, 2343, 2397, 2383, 2337, 2435, 2394, 2468, 2346, 2396, 2398, 2412, 2383, 2418, 2282, 2411, 2441, 2337, 2316, 2361, 2353, 2254, 2230]
```

I want to merge the lists (if these are lists), so that I just have one big list (if that's what that's called) with all the values, so I can use them all as values for the y-axis of my graph.(Like this:

```
[2262, 2299, 2227, 2310, 2240, 2295, 2271, 2316, 2235, 2260, 2269, 2272, 2263, 2302, 2270, 2296, 2353, 2353, 2357, 2298, 2193, 2297, 2393, 2354, 2377, 2336, 2343, 2397, 2383, 2337, 2435, 2394, 2468, 2346, 2396, 2398, 2412, 2383, 2418, 2282, 2411, 2441, 2337, 2316, 2361, 2353, 2254, 2230]
```

)

How do I merge these lists easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a list to hold all your numbers:

```
data = []
```

Inside the loop, call [`list.extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), to add every element of `events_per_hour` to `data` in one call:

```
for dag in range(1, 32):
    ... 
    data.extend(events_per_hour)
```

At the end, `data` holds all your numbers as a single list.

---

**Demo**

```
In [1]: data = []

In [2]: for i in range(3):
   ...:     data.extend([1, 2, 3])
   ...:     

In [3]: data
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```